# How to use ternary operator using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to display a popup like in picture below when hovering on buttons using react and typescript.

[image]

below is my code,

```
function Parent () {
    return (
        <ItemsList>
            {filtereditems.map(item => (
                <Item 
                    key={item.id}
                    item={item}
                />
            ))}
        </ItemsList>
    );
}


const ItemsList = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;  
`;


function Item ({item}: Props) { //this displays the button like components in picture
    return(
        <Wrapper>
            {getShortName(item)}
        </Wrapper>
    );
}


const Wrapper = styled(Icon)`
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
`;


 const Icon = styled.div<Props>`
     width: ${p => (p.size ? `${p.size}px` : '20px')};
     height: ${p => (p.size ? `${p.size}px` : '20px')};
     flex-shrink: 0;
     text-align: center;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
`;
```

Now when i hover on Item component i want to get the popup like in picture above. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Looking for [tooltip](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#tooltips) option?

Comment: Look to onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave (https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events) and a useState in your Parent component : const [hoveredId, setHoveredId] = useState(); ( https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) or alternative solution, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the content of the popup should come (I assume `getShortName()` just shows the button content), however, with the solution below you can solve the problem whatever structure it has. If you have a `span` or whatever inside as the popup/tooltip text, it can be solved like:

```
function Item ({item}: Props) { //this displays the button like components in picture
    return(
        <Wrapper>
            {getShortName(item)}
            <span id='popupOrTooltip'>Whatever you like</span>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}


const Wrapper = styled(Icon)`
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 14px;
`;


 const Icon = styled.div<Props>`
     width: ${p => (p.size ? `${p.size}px` : '20px')};
     height: ${p => (p.size ? `${p.size}px` : '20px')};
     flex-shrink: 0;
     text-align: center;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     & > span {
       opacity: 0;
       visibility: hidden;
     }
     &:hover > span {
       opacity: 1;
       visibility: visible;
     }

`;
```

The `&` operator is from SASS/SCSS, which means the parent selector, `:hover` is the psuedo for if the selector's element is hovered, `>` means direct child(ren).